React Native error trying to connect Mapbox
I followed every step on the starting guide on mapbox react native github repo but im still getting this errors:
ERROR  Error: @rnmapbox/maps native code not available. Make sure you have linked the library and rebuild your app. See https://rnmapbox.github.io/docs/install?rebuild=expo#rebuild, js engine: hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called., js engine: hermes

I tried re-installing everything and adding pluggins to my app.json
